# Why am I getting a blank page when deploying a Holoviews app through Heroku with panel serve?

Tags: python, heroku, bokeh, panel, holoviews

I have connected my github repo to Heroku and am using that to deploy a file called main.py from my main branch. The code in main.py is as follows

```
# In[29]:


# In[30]:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
import holoviews.plotting.bokeh
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from holoviews.selection import link_selections
from holoviews import dim, opts

#from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, rasterize, shade, dynspread, spread
#import holoviews.operation.datashader as hd



# In[31]:


#Post stats
views_df = pd.read_csv("data/wh1_public_views_imps_8345346.csv")
comments_df = pd.read_csv("data/qrc_8345346_responses.csv")


# In[32]:


#Profile / User stats
profiles_df = pd.read_csv("data/rallypoint_production_profiles_7-19-23.csv")
users_df = pd.read_csv("data/rallypoint_production_users_7-19-23.csv")



# In[36]:


users_df["easting"], users_df["northing"] = hv.Tiles.lon_lat_to_easting_northing(
users_df["longitude"], users_df["latitude"]
)



# In[37]:


#Concat the users and profiles df on user id column

users_profiles_df = users_df.merge(profiles_df, on='user_id', how='left')


# In[38]:


#Filter users_profiles_df to just logged in users who have viewed the post, and then drop duplicate viewers

filtered_users_profiles_df = users_profiles_df.merge(views_df, on='profile_id', how='inner')
filtered_users_profiles_df.drop_duplicates(subset='profile_id', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)


# In[39]:


filtered_users_profiles_df['birth_year'] = filtered_users_profiles_df.birth_year.replace(0, np.nan)

filtered_users_profiles_df.drop(columns=['gender.1', 'marital_status.1'], inplace=True)




# In[40]:


#Dataframe for commenter engagement

comments_filtered_df = users_profiles_df.merge(comments_df, on='profile_id', how='inner')
comments_filtered_df.drop_duplicates(subset='profile_id', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)


# In[41]:


filtered_users_profiles_df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(filtered_users_profiles_df.created_at)
filtered_users_profiles_df['created_at_year'] = filtered_users_profiles_df['created_at'].dt.year


# In[42]:


hv.extension('bokeh')

ls = link_selections.instance()

plot_research_dataset = hv.Dataset(filtered_users_profiles_df)

open_street_map = hv.Tiles('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png', name="OSM").opts(width=600, height=550)
points = hv.Points(plot_research_dataset, ['easting', 'northing'], ['birth_year'])

tooltips = [
    ('birth_year', '@birth_year')]

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)

data_points = points.opts(opts.Points(tools=[hover], size=5))

#table = hv.Table(plot_research_dataset, ['INSTNM_cleaned', 'keywords'])
branch_histogram = hv.operation.histogram(plot_research_dataset, dimension='branch_id', normed=False)
profile_created_at_histogram = hv.operation.histogram(plot_research_dataset, dimension='created_at_year', normed=False)



#data_map = rasterize(points, x_sampling=1, y_sampling=1, cmap=cc.fire, width=900, height=480).opts(tools=[hover], fontsize=5)


overlay = open_street_map * data_points

show_plot = ls(overlay) + ls(branch_histogram) + ls(profile_created_at_histogram)
#show_plot

pn.panel(show_plot).servable(title='Updated Holovews App')
```

When I run this same file locally in a virtual environment using 'bokeh serve --show main.py', everything renders as it should at http://localhost:5006/main. But when serving through Heroku I only get a blank white page. The repo is connecting properly as I get the "Updated Holoviews App" text when hovering over the browser tab. Since there are no errors in the Heroku application log, I'm guessing this is an issue with my Holoviews/Bokeh statements to serve the plot rather than a Heroku issue. The Heroku application log is as follows:

"2023-08-03T18:17:31.485568+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-08-03T18:17:31.485568+00:00 app[web.1]:   sys.exit(main())
2023-08-03T18:17:31.487031+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03 18:17:31,486 Starting Bokeh server version 3.2.1 (running on Tornado 6.3.2)
2023-08-03T18:17:32.764914+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03 18:17:32,764 User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
2023-08-03T18:17:32.770631+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03 18:17:32,770 Bokeh app running at: http://0.0.0.0:55173/main
2023-08-03T18:17:32.770704+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03 18:17:32,770 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 2
2023-08-03T18:17:33.086521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-08-03T18:17:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-08-03T18:18:48.344006+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=rp-bokeh-test-baf37200c9e5.herokuapp.com request_id=44007d18-bf9a-494a-8104-e45e89a8b080 fwd="98.115.41.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=302 bytes=183 protocol=https
2023-08-03T18:18:56.350991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/main" host=rp-bokeh-test-baf37200c9e5.herokuapp.com request_id=c137514f-ad1d-42ff-b18b-bf319a69d3ec fwd="98.115.41.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7959ms status=200 bytes=5086 protocol=https "

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Joe

EDIT: The 'data' folder in the code above contains files stored in GitHub LFS. I'm aware that LFS and Heroku don't play nicely together in their native state. I'm using the GitHub LFS buildpack found [here](https://ankane.org/git-lfs-on-heroku) . It's not throwing any errors so I don't think that is the problem, but I could very well be wrong.